# Why doesn't Kinesis Streams Data Viewer show any Agent Events after call through Amazon Connect contact Flow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-connect

QUESTION:  Why don't I see Agent Events in the Data Viewer for the Kinesis Stream I attached to an instance of Amazon Connect?

Here is what I did:

1. Created a Kinesis Stream.  Call it `amzn-conn-agent-events`.
2. In the dashboard for instance of Amazon Connect, I visited `Data Streaming` and enabled data streaming; I selected `amzn-conn-agent-events` for Agent Events, but did not select any Kinesis resource for Contact Trace Records.
3. Logged out of my instance of Amazon Connect, then logged back in.
4. Opened Agent Workspace, and from my cell, called the Connect phone #, was routed to the Agent Workspace, and completed a 30s conversation.
5. Opened dashboard for Kinesis Stream `amzn-conn-agent-events`.
6. Visited `Data Viewer` tab.

At this point, I was expecting to see Agent Events.  There was nothing.  I then selected each of 4 different shards, and pressed on `Get Records` ... still nothing.

What is going on?  How do I get the Agent Events to be pushed into the stream `amzn-conn-agent-events`.

Comment: Just for grins, I also tried adding `amzn-conn-agent-events` as a Kinesis Stream for Contact Trace Records.  I repeated a call into Amazon Connect, revisited the dashboard for `amzn-conn-agent-events`, etc, but not a single Agent or Contact event surfaced in the `Data Viewer`.

Comment: I am guessing this issue is a bug in Amazon Connect.  That is, I first created my Amazon Connect instance **without** Data Streaming enabled; only later did I reconfigure said instance to support Data Streaming.  I am guessing such later edits do not properly attach the Kinesis Stream to the existing Amazon Connect instance ... that is, the Kinesis Stream may be properly attached to the Amazon Connect instance configuration, but the configuration itself is cached in "AWS program memory" and never refreshed.  Someone needs to fix this.

Comment: I created a new instance of Amazon Connect, enabled Data Streaming, and attached the Kinesis Stream `amzn-conn-agent-events` to both Agent Events and Contact Trace Records ... then I made a call to the Agent Workspace ... simulated a conversation ... revisited `Data Viewer` ... and there were NO data records for any of the 4 shards attached to `amzn-conn-agent-events`.  Is it possible there is a permissions issue?  IE, the Amazon Contact instance needs to be permissioned in some way to access Kinesis?

Answer (score 1):

Contact trace records get published when the contact ends (after the agent leaves ACW). However, I'm not sure if that's the case also for agent events. But worth checking!